# How can I elegantly turn user input into a variable name in Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line-interface, user-input, control-flow

I want to use input from the user to pick a hash to operate on. Currently, I have this cumbersome code:

```
my ( %hash1, %hash2 );
print "Which hash to work with (1 or 2)? ";
my $which = <>;
chomp $which;
&do_something( %hash1 ) if $which == 1;
&do_something( %hash2 ) if $which == 2;
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I was thinking of using `%{"hash$which"}`, but that doesn't seem to work. I think

```
$which = "hash" . chomp $which;
&do_something( %{"$which"} );
```

would work, but is that the best way to do it?

Thanks for the help, especially since this is my first SO post.

Comment: Who taught you to call subroutines using `&`? That's a sign of Perl knowledge which is almost twenty years out of date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Why it's stupid to use a variable as a variable name](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

You want

```
my @hashes;
print "Which hash to work with (1 or 2)? ";
my $which = <>;
chomp $which;
do_something( %{ $hashes[$which] } );
```

Just in case you don't know, always use `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: PS — Why did you instruct Perl to disreguard `do_something`'s prototype? Removed the directive (`&`) to do so.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called a "symbolic reference" in the perl world. The use of symbolic references is [strongly](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/style/slide24.html) [discouraged](http://szabgab.com/symbolic-reference-in-perl.html).

Why not add another level of indirection?

```
my $hash = {
    user_opt1 => {
        foo => 'bar',
    },
    user_opt2 => {
        foo => 'baz',
    },
};
```